# Is this a bot fishing for security vulnerabilities on my site?

Tags: web-application, php, vulnerability

I am running a webpage for my family with a feature to track users and guests. Since its all just family stuff no one ever visits this server, and I hardly see more than 2-3 of us logged on at the same time. I did however notice today that I suddenly had 16 guests browsing the site, and when checking the logs they were all from the same IP and requesting the same file.

**Was this a bot sniffing my website for vulnerabilties?**

[image: Security hole in ajaxfilemanager]

Comment: Is your site based on a content management system like Joomla or Wordpress? Does it use PHP? It is seems to be URL brute forcer to me.

Comment: It uses a CMS, but developed by myself. I failed to state in my question that the specific file is not present on my server.

Comment: There have been multiple vulnerabilities in [Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/our-projects/ajax-file-manager-project/), which these requests are trying to locate on your site.

Comment: @Gumbo, you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @all: we surely need a canonical answer for this same type of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These requests seem to try to locate [Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/our-projects/ajax-file-manager-project/), in which [several vulnerabilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=phpletter.com+ajax+file+manager+vulnerability) have been discovered.

If you don’t use that, there is no need to worry.

Comment: But should I worry about having been targeted, or are these bots crawling the web randomly?

Comment: @birdieblue - Perhaps you've been targeted by a bot randomly crawling the web?  It's not necessarily something that you can determine without a **lot** of research.